# Java mutex causing missing input compared to busy loop for multithreaded server?

Tags: java, multithreading, server, client, mutex

I'm writing a Java program that interfaces with a C program on my Linux server (it's a client/server chat program). Right now, I'm implementing a blocking feature for the input to block until the user presses "Enter" before sending the input to the server. To do this, I have two choices: a busy loop, and a mutex. The mutex is obviously the best alternative, but I'm running into an issue where sometimes the input just won't send to the server at all. With the busy loop, though, I just unset a flag and it works fine.

Busy loop:

```
while(!this.inputField.isReady()){}
// send data in inputField to server
this.inputField.setReady(false);
```

So, all I need to do in the textfield (in a keylistener) is:

```
...
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
  if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
    ready = true;
    setText("");
  }
}
...
```

So, yes, this works. My mutex solution isn't so lucky:

```
while (!this.inputField.isReady()) {
  synchronized(this.inputField.mutex) {
    try {
      this.inputField.mutex.wait();
    } ... //redacted for simplicity
  }
}
```

And the notifier:

```
...
ready = true; 
// This is in the TextField class.
synchronized(this.mutex) {
  this.mutex.notify();
}
setText("");
...
```

Maybe I'm misunderstanding a fundamental piece of Java's synchronization capabilities (this is much easier in C...). the mutex is just a standard Object, following online examples. Note that I did try notifyAll, but that didn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mutex does nothing. There is nothing that it protects.

If the shared state is the ready flag, then the mutex must protect the ready flag. So:

```
synchronized(this.inputField.mutex) {
   while (!this.inputField.isReady()) {
    try {
      this.inputField.mutex.wait();
    } ... //redacted for simplicity
  }
}
```

Notice you can't call `isReady` without holding the mutex since the mutex protects the synchronization around readiness. Similarly:

```
...
// This is in the TextField class.
synchronized(this.mutex) {
  ready = true; 
  this.mutex.notify();
}
setText("");
...
```

The mutex must protect the shared state. If the shared state is the ready flag, no thread may access the ready flag without holding the mutex.

You don't show your implementation of `isReady` but if it acquires the mutex itself, that is insufficient. You cannot acquire the mutex, check ready, release the mutex, and then call `wait`. That creates a race condition if the ready flag changes state after `isReady` returns but before you enter `wait`.